# Access Windows phone 8 Registry

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-phone-8, registry

Is it possible for Windows phone apps to access the `WP` registry? I would like to enable **"allow all cookies"** internet settings by editing the registry. Is this possible.?

Or is enabling cookies just for the `WebBrowser` control in my app possible?

I have done some research but in vain. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way to access it, since all WP8 apps are sandboxed.

You could use an external library. Check this out,

[WP8 Native Access](https://wp8nativeaccess.codeplex.com/)